# set language to administrator menu in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

i have develop a component in joomla 1.5 and make .xml file to install
in my .xml i have administrator menu like

```
<administration><menu>COM_MY_COMP</menu>
    <submenu> 
         <menu task="display">COM_MY_COMP_MENU1</menu> 
        <menu task="additem">COM_MY_COMP_MENU2</menu> 
  </submenu>
```

and in language file i set the item like

```
COM_MY_COMP="My Component"
COM_MY_COMP_MENU1="Dispaly"
COM_MY_COMP_MENU2="Dispaly2"
```

it working on other item but not on administrator menu , it is not convert to `COM_MY_COMP` to `My Component`
i use joomla 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just add the language file to the folder. You need to re-install the component WITH the language file. Here is what you need to add to the xml.

```
<languages folder="language-admin"> 
     <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.com_yourcomponent.ini</language> 
     <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.com_yourcomponent.menu.ini</language> 
</languages>
```

Also may I say that if its the menu you are trying to translate, you will need a separate language file like `en-GB.com_yourcomponent.menu.ini`

and below is how it should look.

```
COM_YOURCOMPONENT="Your Component"
COM_YOURCOMPONENT.CONTROL_PANEL="Control Panel"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your translation in this folder:

```
/administrator/language/en-GB/
```

Comment: i have already put file in `/administrator/language/en-GB/`, its work on all items in `administrator` but not on `menu`